# Fit multiple regression model with pairwise deletion (or on a correlation/covariance matrix) in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, covariance, missing-data, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to fit a multiple regression model with pairwise deletion in the context of missing data.  `lm()` uses listwise deletion, which I'd prefer not to use in my case.  I'd also prefer not to use multiple imputation or FIML.  How can I do multiple regression with pairwise deletion in R?

I have tried the `mat.regress()` function of the `psych` package, which fits regression models to correlation/covariance matrices (which can be obtained from pairwise deletion), but the regression model does not appear to include an intercept parameter.

Here's what I've tried (small example):

```
set.seed(33333)
y <- rnorm(1000)
x1 <- y*2 + rnorm(1000, sd=.2)
x2 <- y*5 + rnorm(1000, sd=.5)

y[sample(1:1000, 10)] <- NA
x1[sample(1:1000, 10)] <- NA
x2[sample(1:1000, 10)] <- NA

mydata <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)
covMatrix <- cov(mydata, use="pairwise.complete.obs")

#Listwise Deletion
listwiseDeletion <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=mydata)
observations <- length(listwiseDeletion$na.action) #30 rows deleted due to listwise deletion

coef(listwiseDeletion)
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
0.001995527 0.245372245 0.100001989

#Pairwise Deletion --- but missing intercept
pairwiseDeletion <- mat.regress(y="y", x=c("x1","x2"), data=covMatrix, n.obs=observations)
pairwiseDeletion$beta
       y
x1 0.1861277
x2 0.1251995

#Pairwise Deletion --- tried to add intercept, but received error when fitting model
mydata$intercept <- 0
covMatrixWithIntercept <- cov(mydata, use="pairwise.complete.obs")

pairwiseDeletionWithIntercept <- mat.regress(y="y", x=c("intercept","x1","x2"), data=covMatrixWithIntercept, n.obs=observations)
Something is seriously wrong the correlation matrix.
In smc, smcs were set to 1.0
Warning messages:
1: In cov2cor(C) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
2: In cor.smooth(R) :
  I am sorry, there is something seriously wrong with the correlation matrix,
cor.smooth failed to  smooth it because some of the eigen values are NA.  
Are you sure you specified the data correctly?
```

So, how can I obtain an intercept parameter using `mat.regress`, or how can I obtain parameter estimates from pairwise deletion using another method or package in R?  I've seen [matrix calculations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107597/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-covariance-matrix-to-find-coefficients-for-multiple-re) to do this, but, ideally, there'd be a package that also outputs regression diagnostics, fit stats, etc.  Also, preferably, the method would be able to fit interaction terms.

Comment: Can you clarify why you'd want to do that? What's your goal? This would seem to be invalid under most missing data mechanisms one could imagine.

Comment: I would like to fit a model using pairwise regression to compare it to models fitted using other approaches to handling missingness. I understand that pairwise deletion (i.e., available cases) has stringent assumptions regarding the missing data mechanisms (i.e., MCAR).

Comment: As noted by Gu and Matloff (2015), "We believe that available cases [pairwise deletion] can be a very useful tool. As Marsh notes (Marsh, 1998), available cases 'follows naturally from a desire to use as much of the data as possible.' We will show here that available cases can indeed yield significant improvements in statistical accuracy over complete cases [listwise deletion], while avoiding the very slow computational speed of multiple imputation."

Comment: van buuren mentions lavaan package https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-simplesolutions.html (under pairwise deletion 1.3.2)

Answer (score 2):

The [regtools package](https://github.com/matloff/regtools) was just released and allows pairwise deletion in multiple regression and principal components analysis.  The package is introduced in [this post](https://matloff.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/new-r-softwaremethodology-for-handling-missing-dat/), and is accompanied by [a JSM article](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/Missing.pdf) that compares pairwise deletion (aka available cases), with listwise deletion and multiple imputation. However, the package does not currently include statistical tests of the coefficients, unlike the `lm()` function.