# Show reg y on x in $y_{it} = \beta x_{it} + \theta_{i} + \epsilon_{it} \equiv y_{it} - \bar{y_{I}} = \beta(x_{it} - \bar{x_{I}}) + \epsilon_{it}$

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

So I'm trying to show that regressing y on x in this case (fixed effects model):
$y_{it} = \beta x_{it} + \theta_{i} + \epsilon_{it}$

is the same as this regression:
$y_{it} - \bar{y_{l}} = \beta(x_{it} - \bar{x_{l}}) + \epsilon_{it}$

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: what does that $l$ stand for?

Comment: I think it's a capital "i" to account for the means that fixed effects pull out. I'll edit the problem

Comment: At the moment you have written both models with the same error term, so clearly they are *not* the same.  Even if you fix this, without specifying an error distribution for the two models, you have not even fully specified the models, so it is not possible to compare them and say if they are different.  I suggest you start by changing the error notation on one of the models and then specify your error distributions, so that you have fully specified your two models.

Comment: Here I'll post the problem exactly how it's written in my homework. Hopefully that will help to clarify. If we can't figure out the answer I'll talk to the TA on Tuesday and get back with you guys about it so we have the answer and can discuss it!

Comment: This is demonstrated (in passing) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196807/explicit-solution-for-linear-regression-with-two-predictors/197788#197788 using a technique that (obviously) generalizes to multiple regression.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your first equation as $\bar{y}_i = \beta \bar{x}_i + \theta_i + \bar{\epsilon}_i $. Moreover, notice that $\bar{\epsilon}_i = 0$, because you have $\theta_i$ in the model.

So that the only thing you have to do is to subtract this equation from your first equation so you can reach your second equation. I hope it helped.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. I'm not sure if taking the difference between the original and the expected value of the original conditioned on t would suggest the betas are identical.

Comment: What do the bars on the variables mean?

Comment: The bars are the sample mean.

Comment: Considering the question, there is another way to prove it, using the Frisch Waugh Lovell theorem (this is what the question provided you in parenthesis).  1st you regress y and x on all $\theta_i$. The residual terms from these two regressions are the demeaned variables $y_i - \bar{y}$ and $x_i - \bar{x}$ (I let you to check it by yourself, but it is a very standard result in OLS regression). 2nd you take these residuals and regress $y_i - \bar{y}$ on $x_i - \bar{x}$ . The Frisch Waugh Lovell theorem states that the $

Comment: If that's what the bars are intended to denote, then could you clarify what exactly the other variables refer to?  In particular, would $\beta,$ $\theta,$ and the $\epsilon_i$ be the *model parameters* and *errors* or would they be the *least squares estimates* and *residuals*?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer would use the Frisch Waugh Lovell theorem (this is what the question provided you in parenthesis).

1st you regress y and x on all $\theta_i$. The residual terms from these two regressions are the demeaned variables $y_i - \bar{y}$ and $x_i - \bar{x}$ (It is a standard result in OLS regression). 
2nd you regress these residuals each other. I.e. regress $y_i - \bar{y}$ on $x_i - \bar{x}$. The Frisch Waugh Lovell theorem states that the $\hat{\beta}$ from this regression is numerically identical to the original regression.