# Formulas for multivariate meta-regression

Tags: weighted-regression, multivariate-regression, meta-regression, wls

everyone!

I'm digging in meta-regression and doing hand calculations using WLS to get better understanding of the topic. I'm fine with calculations for univariative model (that is, 1 covariate is considered) but faced problems when several predictors are considered. I use following formulas for univariative model:

**1. intercept and slope**

[image]

**2. variance for intercept, slope, and corresponding mean squared error**

[image]

[image]

**3. F-test for estimation of between-study variance in random-effects model**
[image]

*w - weight; y - outcome; x - predictor

My question is how should I modify and extend these formulas for multivariative case when two, three, and more predictors are accounted for? In particular, formulas for variance and F-test are of interest (I guess, covariance is supposed to be incorporated there).

The available infromation on Internet consideres this topic in matrix form, but I ask for the answer in scalar form (not a  mathematician, unfortunately).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Several predictors makes this *multiple* regression.  "Multivariate" regression involves several *response* variables that might be associated.  It is not productive to request the multiple regression formulas in "scalar form," because they rapidly get too complicated: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196807/

Comment: Seem to be confused like many other people, even literature often uses multivariate and multiple in other way. The complexity of formulas is anticipated, so, the answer is still needed.

Comment: The problem is that the length of the formula grows exponentially in the number of independent variables, even when you use vector products or summation notation. It is neither practical nor of any analytical interest to write it out for more than two or three variables; two ought to be enough.  Indeed, implementing such a formula in software (or by hand) isn't a good idea anyway, because there are algorithms with better numerical stability.

Comment: I got the point, thanks. Assumed this looking at initial formulas. To end-up with the topic, is it possible to give me the input at least for two predictors case? This will be enough for my purpose, yet formulas still have to be managable.

Comment: Follow the link in my first comment for the formulas with two predictors.

Comment: Did it. Also checked the paper reffered in that topic. They give half an answer. I miss how the weight should be incroporated that formulas correctly. Also calcualtion of variances and F-test aren't covered. I appologize for being annoying.