# Derive Conditional Variance from Covariance Matrix

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, conditional-probability, covariance-matrix, conditional-expectation

Given the mean, variance, and covariance of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, how would I find $\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)$?

I know that I can find $E(Y\mid X)$ using the definition of covariance and finding $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ then dividing by $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Would I try to find $\mathbb{E}[Y^2\mid X]?$
Or would I try to use the total conditional variance? I'm very confused.

Comment: It's not possible in general. Mean, variance and covariance do not entirely determine the joint law of $X$ and $Y$. This is the case if you assume that $(X,Y)$ follows a bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: How would this change if they are a joint normal? I'm not quite seeing it.

Comment: A bivariate normal distribution is entirely determined by the means, the variances and the covariance.

Comment: Oh! That's right. So given the multivariate PDF of $f(x,y)$, to find the conditional variance, would I divide by the PDF of $Y$ to get $f_(Y|X)$ then derive the first and second moments to find the conditional variance?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case does it help ?

Comment: You can readily estimate the conditional variance in terms of the statistics you have, because they are all you need in order to perform ordinary least squares regression.  If the OLS assumptions are applicable (particularly that the model is correct and the errors are homoscedastic), this would solve your problem.  It does not require the stronger assumption of bivariate normality.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107597 for further explanation and working code.

Comment: Does the second paragraph mean you think $E(Y \mid X) = E(XY)/E(X)$? If not, can you clarify how you intend to find $E(Y\mid X)$ from the information given?