# Is there a way to use the covariance matrix to find coefficients for multiple regression WITHOUT intercept?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, covariance-matrix, intercept

Given:
$$
y=\alpha + \beta x
$$
The problem on how to get regression coefficients $\alpha, \beta_0, \beta_1,...,\beta_n$ from the covariance matrix is solved here:

[Is there a way to use the covariance matrix to find coefficients for multiple regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107597/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-covariance-matrix-to-find-coefficients-for-multiple-re)

The same problem can be solved without the intercept ($\alpha =0$)?

$$
y=\beta x
$$

My MATLAB code:

````
function [coefficients, intercept] = gvcoef(X,y,CovEst)
%
% Finds coefficients and intercept estimates
% Inputs:
% - y -> dependent variable vector nx1
% - X -> independent variables matrix nxp
% - cov -> given estimate of covariance matrix (cov(X) in OLS)

a = CovEst;

for i=1:size(X,2)
    covariance = cov(y,X(:,i));
    b(i,:)= covariance(1,2);
end

% Coefficients from the covariance matrix
coefficients = linsolve(a,b);

% Intercept
y_bar = mean(y);
x_bar = mean(X,1);
intercept = y_bar - x_bar * coefficients;

end
```
````

Comment: If I understand your question, the solution is the same. Just follow the answer you linked to until they obtain the coefficients.

Comment: I edited my question to include the code I am using. I do not understand why I get the intercept estimate even if I do not include a ones column in the X matrix