# linear model estimator proof

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, linear-algebra

For a linear model, the noncentered form is 
$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+...+\beta_kx_{ik}+\epsilon_i$ ---(a)
the centered form is 
$Y_i=\alpha+\beta_1(x_{i1}-\bar{x}_1)+...+\beta_k(x_{ik}-\bar{x}_k)+\epsilon_i$ ---(b) 
And we know that the matrix form of the centered form is 
$Y=[j_n,X_c] (\alpha,\beta^*)'+\epsilon$ where $X_c=(I-\frac{1}{n}J_n)X$, $X=[X_1,...,X_k]$. 
We could show that the estimators for $\alpha$ and $\beta^*$ are $\hat{\alpha}=\bar{Y}$ and $\hat{\beta}^*=(X_c'X_c)^{-1}X_c'Y$

**My question is:**  
**How to show $\hat{\beta}^*$ is the same as the last three elements of $\hat{\beta}=(X_a'X_a)^{-1}X_a'Y$, where $X_a=[j_n,X]$. What is the relationship between $\hat{\alpha}$ and the first element of $\hat{\beta}$?**

Comment: What you ask to show isn't true.  You seem to assume there are just three explanatory variables.  Because this question concerns the relationship between the uncentered and centered formulas, perhaps you will find https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/108862/919 helpful: it shows how centering amounts to one row-reduction pass ("Gaussian elimination") in solving the original (uncentered) equations.

Comment: That's how the question was asked....But if you assume there are only three explanatory variables, how would you prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to answering the question is to use the inverse of a 2x2 block matrix.  The following formula is useful.  Suppose $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ are invertible, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{A} & \boldsymbol{B} \\
\boldsymbol{C} & \boldsymbol{D}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} &=& \begin{pmatrix}
\left(\boldsymbol{A}-\boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{D}^{-1}\boldsymbol{C}\right)^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & \left(\boldsymbol{D}-\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{B}\right)^{-1}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{I} & -\boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{D}^{-1} \\
-\boldsymbol{C}\boldsymbol{A}^{-1} & \boldsymbol{I}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Consider the partition $\boldsymbol{X}_a = \left[\boldsymbol{j}_n, \boldsymbol{X}\right]$.  Likewise, we shall partition the regression parameters into an intercept term and slope terms
\begin{eqnarray*}
\boldsymbol{\beta} = \begin{pmatrix}
\beta_0 \\
\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\ast}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Clearly, $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \left(\boldsymbol{X}_a^{\prime} \boldsymbol{X}_a\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}_a^{\prime} \boldsymbol{y}$.  Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\widehat{\beta}_0 \\
\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{\ast}
\end{pmatrix} &=& \begin{pmatrix}
n & \boldsymbol{j}_n^{\prime} \boldsymbol{X} \\
\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{j}_n & \boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{X}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{j}_n^{\prime} \boldsymbol{y} \\
\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{y}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=& \begin{pmatrix}
\left(n -\boldsymbol{j}_n^{\prime} \boldsymbol{X} \left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{j}_n\right)^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & \left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime} \left[\boldsymbol{I}_n - \frac{\boldsymbol{J}_n}{n}\right]\boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-1}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{j}_n^{\prime}\left[\boldsymbol{I}_n - \boldsymbol{X} \left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\right]\boldsymbol{y} \\
\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime}\left[\boldsymbol{I}_n - \frac{\boldsymbol{J}_n}{n}\right]\boldsymbol{y}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I have one more follow-up question. The first element I got is $\frac{j_n'(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')Y}{j_n'(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')j_n}$. What's the relationship with $\hat{\alpha}=\bar{Y}$? I tried to simplify $\frac{j_n'(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')Y}{j_n'(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')j_n}$ but the denominator turns 0 (I assume $Mj_n=j_n$?)

Comment: Clearly $\widehat{\beta}_0 = \widehat{\alpha} - \frac{j_n^{\prime}}{n} \boldsymbol{X} \widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{\ast}$.  Next, use the Sherman-Morrison formula to reduce the term $\left(\boldsymbol{X}^{\prime} \left[\boldsymbol{I}_n - \frac{\boldsymbol{J}_n}{n} \right] \boldsymbol{X}\right)^{-1}$ and it should simply to the formula you are working with.  Just work in the other direction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: How did you get $\hat{\beta}_0=\hat{\alpha}-\frac{j_n'}{n}X\hat{\beta}^*$ so qucikly?

Comment: I might need more details.....

Comment: Compare the model in centered form and uncentered form.  In the uncentered form, we have the intercept term $\beta_0$, not depending on changing covariates, whereas in the centered form we must collect all terms $\alpha - \frac{\boldsymbol{j}_n^{\prime}}{n} \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\beta}^{\ast}$ to obtain the total intercept term.  You can reparametrize these into the single term $\beta_0$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much