Inverse of Sums of Squares and Cross Products (SSCP) matrix
In Chapter 3 of the book Applied Linear Regression, Weisberg suggested that the inverse of the corrected SSCP matrix, $(\chi^T\chi)^{-1}$, is all but the first row and column of the inverse of the uncorrected SSCP matrix, $(X^TX)^{-1}$. Why is that?
$\chi$ is simply $X$ but without the intercept and with the respective mean subtracted from each column, FYI.

They are probably referring to the relationship to the covariance matrix described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/108862/919.

Keeping aside the argument that Weisberg suggested this to avoid computation inaccuracies, what he is dealing with is a no-intercept model.
To answer your question as for why it is so, one needs to write the original design matrix $\mathbf X $  as $[\mathrm{1\! \! 1}_n,~ \mathbf X_1],~\mathbf X_1:=[\mathbf x_1,\ldots,\mathbf x_p].$ Owing to $\mathrm{1\! \! 1}_n^\top\mathbf X_1=n\bar{\mathbf x}^\top, $ where $\bar{\mathbf x}^\top:=[\bar x_{\cdot 1}, \ldots, \bar x_{\cdot p}], $
$$\left(\mathbf{X^\top X}\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}n & n\bar{\mathbf x}^\top\\n\bar{\mathbf x} & \mathbf X_1^\top\mathbf X_1\end{bmatrix}^{-1};$$ using the formula of inverse of a partitioned symmetric matrix (cf. $\eqref{3}$), this yields $$\left(\mathbf {X^\top X}\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1/n + \bar{\mathbf x}^\top\mathbf S^{-1}\bar {\mathbf x}&-\bar{\mathbf x}^\top\mathbf S^{-1}\\-\mathbf S^{-1}\bar{\mathbf x}&\mathbf S^{-1}\end{bmatrix},\tag 1\label 1$$ where $\mathbf S:=\mathbf{X}_1^\top \mathbf{X}_1-n\bar{\mathbf x}\bar{\mathbf x}^\top.$
(Not that this is asked, but since this close, one can check the estimates in no-intercept model: write $\mathbf b:=\begin{bmatrix}b_0\\\mathfrak b\end{bmatrix},$ where $b_0$ is the intercept. Then the ols
$$\hat{\mathbf b}=\begin{bmatrix}1/n + \bar{\mathbf x}^\top\mathbf S^{-1}\bar {\mathbf x}&-\bar{\mathbf x}^\top\mathbf S^{-1}\\-\mathbf S^{-1}\bar{\mathbf x}&\mathbf S^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}n\bar{y} \\ \mathbf X_1^\top\mathbf y\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then from $\eqref 1,$ after calculations, one has \begin{align}\hat{\mathfrak b}&=\mathbf S^{-1}(\mathbf X_1^\top\mathbf y-n\bar{  y}\bar{\mathbf x}),\\ \hat b_0&= \bar y-\bar{\mathbf x}^\top\hat{\mathfrak b}.\end{align})
Look at $\mathbf S$ again: $n\bar{\mathbf x}\bar{\mathbf x}^\top =\{n\bar x_{\cdot i}\bar x_{\cdot j}\}, ~\mathbf S=\{\sum_\ell x_{\ell I}x_{\ell j}- n\bar x_{\cdot i}\bar x_{\cdot j}\}; ~i,j =\overline{1,2,\ldots, p}.$ Now $\boldsymbol{\mathcal X}=\mathbf X_1-\mathrm{1\! \! 1}_n\bar{\mathbf x}^\top;$ so $\bf S $ can be seen to be equal to $\boldsymbol{\mathcal X}^\top\boldsymbol{\mathcal X}.$ So, from $\eqref 1$ again $$\left(\mathbf {X^\top X}\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1/n + \bar{\mathbf x}^\top\mathbf S^{-1}\bar {\mathbf x}&-\bar{\mathbf x}^\top\mathbf S^{-1}\\-\mathbf S^{-1}\bar{\mathbf x}&\left(\boldsymbol{\mathcal X}^\top\boldsymbol{\mathcal X}\right)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}.$$ This is what Weisberg plausibly wanted to mean.

Appendix:

The inverse of a partitioned full rank symmetric matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf X^\top\\\mathbf Z^\top\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf X & \mathbf Z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{X^\top X}&\mathbf{X^\top Z}\\ \mathbf{Z^\top X} &\mathbf{Z^\top Z}\end{bmatrix}\equiv \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf A & \mathbf B\\ \mathbf B^\top &\mathbf D\end{bmatrix}$ is given by $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf A^{-1}+\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf{BW^\top }\mathbf{A}^{-1}&-\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf{BW}\\-\mathbf{WB^\top}\mathbf A^{-1} &\mathbf W\end{bmatrix},\tag{A1}\label 3$ where $\mathbf W:= \left(\mathbf D-\mathbf{B^\top}\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf B\right) ^{-1}.$

--
Reference:
Linear Models, S. R. Searle, $1971, $ Jon Wiley & Sons., sec. $3.2.$
